# Cant find any info on this method being removed in webform or how to fix

Tags: 8, webforms

I am writing a patch for a module that used an old beta or even alpha of webform for drupal 8.

There is a line `WebformEntityReferenceItem::getEntityWebformFieldName($node);` in the module that errors out saying `getEntityWebformFieldName()` does not exist and sure enough in `Drupal\webform\Plugin\Field\FieldType\WebformEntityReferenceItem` the method does not exist.

I checked an older release and the method was there at some point. I've been searching since yesterday but cannot find a workaround or even an answer as to why it was removed. Any ideas?

***EDIT***

So I managed to get it working, but this certainly seems like the incorrect way to do it.

`$node->get('webform')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];`

So it seems `WebformEntityReferenceItem::getEntityWebformFieldName($node);` just gets the webform on the webform node and then grabs its 'target_id' value.

```
$webform_field_name = WebformEntityReferenceItem::getEntityWebformFieldName($node);
$webform_id = $node->$webform_field_name->target_id;
```

What I posted in my edit, I do not believe is the correct solution, albeit it is now working. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Run update.php, clear cache, should fix it

Comment: Sorry, I meant I am writing a patch to update the module. Not apply an update. I'll edit my post. @Clive

Comment: What is your final goal? Are you after the webform itself, or its submissions?  You might want to take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244574/programmatically-get-webform-submissions-of-a-specific-nodes-webform

Comment: @Neograph734 I needed the webform id when using webform node. `WebformEntityReferenceItem::getEntityWebformFieldName();` doesn't appear to exist anymore as of webform 8-rc1. I want to know what to replace that with. I cannot find any mention of it being removed. The line in my edit seems to have fixed the module I am patching, but it seems hacky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WebformEntityReferenceItem::getEntityWebformFieldName() static method was not removed but it was refactored and moved to the 'webform.entity_reference_manager'service.

Here is an example of showing how to use the service.

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformEntityReferenceManagerInterface $entity_reference_manager */
$entity_reference_manager = \Drupal::service('webform.entity_reference_manager');
$field_name = $entity_reference_manager->getFieldName($node);
...
```

@see [\Drupal\webform\WebformEntityReferenceManager](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/WebformEntityReferenceManager.php)

@see [\Drupal\webform\WebformEntityReferenceManagerInterface](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/WebformEntityReferenceManagerInterface.php)

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for all the work you've done for this module

Comment: I am trying to get this working and I am doing: `WebformEntityReferenceManager::getFieldName($node);`, but getting an error saying `Error: Using $this when not in object context`where $node is of type `Drupal\node\Entity\Node` I must be calling this incorrectly but cant figure it out. If I call the method through the interface it says non static methods can be called statically. Any ideas?

Comment: I added a code example to my answer.